# How to make Jquery nested Ajax tabs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Could anybody help me out to get nested tabs through ajax calls.

Description:
I am having Jquery Tabs with ajax option

CODE:

```
$( ".has_ajax_tabs" ).tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
            error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                $( anchor.hash ).html("<h3>OOPS...Something went wrong!</h3> Couldn't load this tab at this time. Please try again later.");
            }
        },
        spinner: "Loading...",
        fxSlide: true
    });
```

HTML CODE:

```
 <div id="tabs" class="has_ajax_tabs">
                                 <ul>
                                     <li><a href="#tabs-1">Profile Details</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="nestedTabsLink.php">Users</a></li>
                                 </ul>

 <div id="tabs-1">  Profile Details form here </div> </div>
```

nestedTabsLink.php loaded by Ajax call

```
<div id="tabs-nested" class="has_ajax_tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-inner1">Inner Tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-inner2">Inner Tab2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-inner1">
        Nested Tabs1
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-inner2">
        Nested Tabs2
    </div>
</div>
```

ERROR: The loaded nestedTabsLink.php file also having tabs which is not working if loaded by Ajax. Without Ajax it works perfect. Can anybody help me to get the code snippet/guidelines?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So if you would op the nestedTabsLink.php file you would also have a tab-setup right?

Using ajax, the javascript inside the requested page isn't parsed. The best way to solve this is by adding a function that runs after the page was loaded. So you could copy the code for the tabs inside nestedTabsLink.php and paste it inside the complete-event of the ajax call.

Comment: I hope repetition of code is not a good idea. There should be some workaround there. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: You could try to user eval() to parse the javascript, by running trough all the <script> tags in the requested page and then eval their contents, but EVAL is definitely not the way to go([link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)! Do you have a online example of this? I would like to check out your code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'd better increase your accept rate.

If I understand right, you are not loading scripts that perform "tabs magic" on the second group of tabs. There are an option to make it work of course, but I would suggest revising an overall architecture. You shouldn't load HTML markup via AJAX calls, as it's redundant. Load just the data needed and than render the data with JS as you need.

Comment: Second of all, nested tabs is bad UI-design http://homepage.mac.com/bradster/iarchitect/tabs.htm

Comment: Agreed. but in my case page is so lengthy that have to be divided into two sections for better accessibility and load balance through ajax. So I would like to keep tabs to load through ajax. And also it is only two tier tabbed structure.